# Cannot locate core file with abrt-hook-cpp installed

Tags: linux, core-file

I've been led to understand that if abrt-ccpp.service is installed on a Linux PC, it supersedes/overwrites (I've read both, not sure which is true) the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, which otherwise specifies the location and filename pattern of core files.

**Question**:

When I execute `systemctl`, why does abrt-ccpp.service report `exited` under the `SUB` column? I don't understand the combination of `active` and `exited`: is the service "alive"/active/running or not?

```
> systemctl
UNIT                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB
abrt-ccpp.service    loaded active exited ...
```

**Question**:

Where are core files generated? I wrote this program to generate a `SIGSEGV`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envz[])
{
  int* pInt = NULL;
  std::cout << *pInt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution as follows:

```
> g++ main.cpp
> ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But I cannot locate where the core file is generated.

**What I have tried**:

- Looked in the same directory as my `main.cpp`. Core file is not there.
- Looked in `/var/tmp/abrt/` because of the following comment in `/etc/abrt/abrt.conf`. Core file is not there.

...

```
# Specify where you want to store coredumps and all files which are needed for
# reporting. (default:/var/tmp/abrt)
#
# Changing dump location could cause problems with SELinux. See man_abrt_selinux(8).
#
#DumpLocation = /var/tmp/abrt
```

...

- Looked in `/var/spool/abrt/` because of a comment at [this link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61536). Core file is not there.
- Edited `/etc/abrt/abrt.conf` and uncommented and set `DumpLocation = ~/foo` which is an existing directory. Followed this by restarting abrt-hook-ccpp (`sudo service abrt-ccpp restart`) and rerunning `a.out`. Core file was not generated in `~/foo/`
- Verified that `ulimit -c` reports `unlimited`.

I am out of ideas of what else to try and where else to look.

In case helpful, this is the content of my `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`:

```
> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e
```

Can someone help explain how the abrt-hook-ccpp service works and where it generates core files? Thank you.

Comment: You can simply just modify your `core_pattern` to point to a pre-defined directory. I always do it this way if I'm not up to figuring out how all these clever core-catching services work.

Comment: Your suggestion worked - thank you. Could you post this as an answer? In addition to crediting your answer, I had unexpected problems (eventually solved) editing core_pattern, and wanted to ask follow-up questions about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to credit https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh who answered this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343240/cannot-locate-core-file-with-abrt-hook-cpp-installed.

The answer was to add this line in file `/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf`

```
ProcessUnpackaged = yes
```

The comment from @daniel-kamil-kozar was also a viable workaround.